# Branch is in master without merging in master before that

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, gitlab

we use git on terminal and gitlab. We have three server environments Dev, Stage(stage branch) and Production(master).

The problem is that we have one branch which is created from master and this branch is merged into our stage branch which is used in the Stage server. We have never merged this branch into master. But the changes from its commit are there when I open on git blame - its changes are there. Its commit is in master. I checked the whole history in gitlab, graphs etc. etc. and this branch is nowhere merged into master. Its not merged in another branch which might be merged in master. I cannot find anything in the way of this branch to master.

How can I understand where this is branch is merged from?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can paste snapshot of graphs or outputs of "git log" to understand the issue better (you can black out any sensitive info). I'd also suggest changing the title to "Commits in staging branch found in master branch without merging".

Comment: it looks like a tool have merged it for you ...    but I m not sure of it due to your description ... Please give use a graph or log  :) thx

Comment: To decide how the branch merged into `master` branch, the commit history is quite necessary, so that other members can make correct suggest. So can you add the graph of the commit history or the model for how the branches and commits are structured?

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --ancestry-path BRANCH..MASTER
```

will show you all commits which are strictly between branch and master. You could add --graph or --oneline at your taste

Answer (score -2):

Since the stage branch is merged from Master. Any time a commit is written to the stage branch, the commits will also be written to Master. It is like having two "Master" branches. Hopefully the answer helped and below is a link reference of the git merge command.

Here is a link to git [merge](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) works. The link goes to the atlassian git tutorial website.

--------edit---------

I do apologize for any misunderstanding from my original post above.

Mistake #1: I thought Master is the name for the branch in the Stage server.

Mistake #2: I thought git merge copy the head pointer address and all commits from one branch node to another branch node.

Correction to Mistake #1: Master and Stage are the names for the server.

Correction to Mistake #2: git merge command only copies commits from one branch to another branch node. Not the head pointer address.

My suggestion, as discussed in the comments of your post by other users, please show some of the logs and/or graphs to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by merged from master ? I have never seen a commit "written" to both local branches without cherry-picking. Please add some examples of how this works.

Comment: @dparker I misunderstand what is meant by master and stage by the original post. Also misunderstood the functionality of git merge. I will be making edits to correct my mistakes.